# Capture text between two variables with Regex

Tags: regex, sharepoint

I am using an add on to SharePoint that allows me to parse incoming data from emails with a Regular Expression and assign it to fields.

I use it extensively, but have come across a situation where I can't get the Regular Expression quite right.

Here is a sample text NOTE: It is all on ONE LINE, no breaks:

```
Web-form &quot;Detailed Quote&quot;Request a Quotefull_name&#58; John Doe;email_address&#58; email@domain.com;
```

I want to pull out John Doe from this.

I was using this expression: `(?<=full_name&#58; )(.*)(?=;)`

But since it is all on one line, it is seeing the `;` at the end and pulling everything from the first variable back to that one.

Here it is in regex: http://regexr.com?38k7d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By `.*` you are using greedy. So make non-greedy using a question mark after that, i.e. `.*?` that will stop at the first `;` after your lookbehind matching.

```
(?<=full_name: )(.*?)(?=;)
```